# Instagram API 'basic' permission review time [in pending mode since ~12 days]

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm writing to you guys as we're tried everything to reach Instagram Developer Support team, without any success so far. *(Mail, contact form, help center, ...)*
We're developing an app that basically helps people print their photos online, and we have a very important part of the service that uses the Instagram basic permissions to allow users to Instagram Login and select their photos to be printed.
After reading the documentation and guidelines numerous of times *(even if that's not our first app)*, we decided to submit our app to leave the Sandbox Mode. However it's now been **12 days** and we're still in pending... We can't modify nor submit again the app, we're kinda stuck at the moment.
Does anyone is facing the same issue? Is this linked to the recent Instagram API deprecation rush (after the FB scandal)?
Anyone in the same situation?

[Instagram app in pending mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrmZc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently Instagram has stopped accepting submissions of new apps, That is the reason you are facing this problem to create new access token. https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/

Although for the already registered app, you can still get more access token by adding the additional new users.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/03/26/facebook-platform-changes/

Pause app review: We paused app review last week while we implement new changes to our platform.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: Indeed it seems clearer now, thanks for the links.

Comment: Is there any solution or need to contact `Instagram`?